# How to load multiple csv files with shuffled columns?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have multiple csv files which I want to load into hive table, my problem is that, sequence of  my csv file header is not fixed.

If I have two csv files

```
sample1.csv 

  column1,column2
      "A","B"
```

and

```
sample2.csv

column2,column1
"A","B"
```

I'm trying with below code code.

```
spark.sql("drop table if exists faizan.sample")
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("wholeFile", true).option("multiline",true).option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", true).option("escape","\"").csv("faizan/sample/sample/sample1.csv", "faizan/sample/sample/sample3.csv")
val newNames = Seq("column1","column2") 
val dfRenamed = df.toDF(newNames: _*)
    dfRenamed.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")
val tempDf = spark.sql("select * from tempTable where")
    tempDf.write.saveAsTable("faizan.sample")
```

I'm getting output :

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      A      B|
|      A      B|
+-------+-------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      A      B|
|      B      A|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I wish spark is that smart enough to resolve the unordered columns in different files.

Try loading them one by one, But you always create 2 data frames and union them.

```
val dfReader = spark.read.format("csv").option("wholeFile", true).option("multiline",true).option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", true).option("escape","\"")

val df1 = dfReader.csv("faizan/sample/sample/sample1.csv")
val df2 = dfReader.csv("faizan/sample/sample/sample3.csv")

val df = df1.union(df2)
```

Other things you can try, using inferSchema as false, create your own schema as

```
StructType(Array(StructField("column1", StringType),StructField("column2", StringType)))
```

Comment: It is not solving the issue, still I'm getting same result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below solution will help to solve your problem

```
val df1 = spark.read.format.....(filepath1)
val df2 = spark.read.format.....(filepath2)
```

Import `col` method from sql.fucntions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
```

convert Seq(col_name1,col_name2) or Seq(String) to Seq(Column)

basically `df1.columns` will return Array[String] column names.

so we should convert Array[String] to Array[Column] like below

```
 val cols = df1.columns.map(e=>col(e))
```

then do the `union` transformation `with selecting converted ordered cols of df1` on dataframe2

```
  df1.union(df2.select(cols:_*))
```